# PHP: Find number of different letters in a string

Tags: php

I want to find how many unique characters a string contains. Examples:

```
"66615888"    contains 4 digits (6 1 5 8).
"12333333345" contains 5 digits (1 2 3 4 5).
```

Comment: Do you care about the order in which the numbers (characters) are returned?

Comment: Question as asked is asking for "how many" unique characters, rather than a list of them.

Comment: @Floris I don't, only need "how many".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
echo count( array_unique( str_split( '66615888')));
```

[Demo](http://viper-7.com/DWMBje)

Docs:

1. [`count()`](http://php.net/count) - Count the number of elements in an array
2. [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) - Find the unique elements in an array
3. [`str_split()`](http://php.net/str_split) - Split a string into an array

Comment: +1 But let me ask: Do you know which performs better: your solution or merlin2011's/NikiC's?

Comment: @insertusernamehere I dont know. which one is better?

Comment: @insertusernamehere - A [simple test](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wWE7j3) tells me NikiC's is faster after 1,000,000 iterations. I prefer this way as IMO it is more readable.

Comment: Thanks for testing. I thought that creating the array will produce some overhead and a direct string manipulation might be faster. But if this runs only a few times, in the end it's only micro optimization.

Answer (score 11):

[`count_chars`](http://php.net/count_chars) gives you a map of `char => frequency`, which you can sum up with with [`array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum):

```
$count = array_sum(count_chars($str));
```

Alternatively you can use the `3` mode for `count_chars` which will give you a string containing all unique characters:

```
$count = strlen(count_chars($str, 3));
```

Comment: I prefer this answer over the "accepted" one. Creating an array of all the elements is a lot of overhead - `count_chars(,3)` is the most direct way to get all the unique characters, and the `strlen` of that is the count - which is what was asked. It gets my vote.

Answer (score 4):

PHP has a function that counts characters.

```
$data = "foobar";
$uniqued = count_chars($data, 3);// return string(5) "abfor"
$count = strlen($uniqued);
```

Please see the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script:

```
<?php
  $str1='66615888';
  $str2='12333333345';
  echo 'The number of unique characters in "'.$str1.'" is: '.strlen(count_chars($str1,3)).' ('.count_chars($str1,3).')'.'<br><br>';
  echo 'The number of unique characters in "'.$str2.'" is: '.strlen(count_chars($str2,3)).' ('.count_chars($str2,3).')'.'<br><br>';
?>
```

Output:

The number of unique characters in "66615888" is: 4 (1568)

The number of unique characters in "12333333345" is: 5 (12345)

---

Here PHP string function `count_chars()` in mode `3` produces an array having all the unique characters.

PHP string function `strlen()` produces total number of unique characters present.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version that also works with multibyte strings:

```
echo count(array_keys(array_flip(preg_split('//u', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY))));
```